# Convert an object into Json using SBJson or other JSON library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I need a easy to use library whit examples  for converting NSObjects to JSON and back again, I found a ton of parseing examples on the net for parsing JSon but not too much on converting NSObject to JSON using SBJSON, Anybody body have a good tutorial or a sample code to convert NSObject to JSON ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `SBJson`, to convert a object to JSON string, you have to override the `proxyForJson` method. Like the following,

The .h file,

```
@interface MyCustomObject : NSObject {
    NSString *receiverFirstName;
    NSString *receiverMiddleInitial;
    NSString *receiverLastName;
    NSString *receiverLastName2;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *receiverFirstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *receiverMiddleInitial;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *receiverLastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *receiverLastName2;

- (id) proxyForJson;
- (int) parseResponse :(NSDictionary *) receivedObjects;
}
```

In the implementation file,

```
    - (id) proxyForJson {

        return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            receiverFirstName, @"ReceiverFirstName",
            receiverMiddleInitial, @"ReceiverMiddleInitial",
            receiverLastName, @"ReceiverLastName",
            receiverLastName2, @"ReceiverLastName2",
            nil ];
    }
```

And to get the object from the JSON string you have to write a `parseResponse` method like this,

```
- (int) parseResponse :(NSDictionary *) receivedObjects {
    self.receiverFirstName = (NSString *) [receivedObjects objectForKey:@"ReceiverFirstName"];
    self.receiverLastName = (NSString *) [receivedObjects objectForKey:@"ReceiverLastName"];

    /* middleInitial and lastname2 are not required field. So server may return null value which
     eventually JSON parser return NSNull. Which is unrecognizable by most of the UI and functions.
     So, convert it to empty string. */ 
    NSString *middleName = (NSString *) [receivedObjects objectForKey:@"ReceiverMiddleInitial"];
    if ((NSNull *) middleName == [NSNull null]) {
        self.receiverMiddleInitial = @"";
    } else {
        self.receiverMiddleInitial = middleName;
    }

    NSString *lastName2 = (NSString *) [receivedObjects objectForKey:@"ReceiverLastName2"];
    if ((NSNull *) lastName2 == [NSNull null]) {
        self.receiverLastName2 = @"";
    } else {
        self.receiverLastName2 = lastName2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

With SBJSON, it's really simple.

```
NSString *myDictInJSON = [myDict JSONRepresentation];
NSString *myArrayInJSON = [myArray JSONRepresentation];
```

Of course, to go the other way array, do:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [myDictInJSON JSONValue];
NSArray *myArray = [myArrayInJSON JSONValue];
```

Comment: sow it only acceped dictionary or array's to convert ? and if so is ther a way to convert a NSObject to dictonary or do i have to create it manualy?

Comment: by default, I believe so. logically, it should also accept casted subclasses, like so: `[(NSDictionary *)myCustomDict JSONRepresentation]`, as long as your subclass doesn't make any changes the to fundamentals of the class.

Comment: it won't, however, work on any arbitrary NSObject, because an NSObject is not (necessarily) a set of key/value pairs, or a list. in order to do this, i would suggest iterating through the values of the NSObject, and making an NSDictionary out of that. or, if you're subclassing NSObject, maybe consider having a method `-dictionaryForm`, which would do the same

Comment: Can I use `JSONValue` to convert an `NSMutableArray` to a JSON string? If so which class is it in? Because I imported `SBJSON.h` and it doesn't have it. Tried with `JSONRepresentation`, i works but it says its deprecated now.

Comment: @Isuru If possible, you should just be using [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you can. Otherwise, `NSMutableArray` should `-JSONRepresentation` without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

From JSON String to Objects:

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

// gives array as output

id objectArray = [parser objectWithString:@"[1,2,3]"]; 

// gives dictionary as output

id objectDictionary = [parser objectWithString:@"{\"name\":\"xyz\",\"email\":\"xyz@email.com\"}"];
```

From Objects to JSON String:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];

id *objectArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello",@"World", nil];

// Pass an Array or Dictionary object.

id *jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:objectArray];
```