# NSString to JSON object

Tags: iphone, json, nsstring

I have a string as follows :

```
{:userid => "user", :password => "123"}
```

I am posting this string to server at login. But the server is accepting everything in the form of JSON object. So I need to convert this string into JSON object.

Also, the server is again returning the response as a JSON object. So how to convert it back to NSString?

Comment: Try to use SBJSON

so, lookup this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844571/convert-an-object-into-json-using-sbjson-or-other-json-library

Comment: JSONKit is the fastest, no point using anything else: https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either parse JSON yourself or use one of the available JSON libraries for iphone.

You can use: 
json-framework or jsonkit or TouchJSON

Answer (score 0):

The [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) project can help you with this.
It allows you to do the following:

```
NSError *error;
CJSONSerializer *serializer = [CJSONSerializer serializer];
NSData *stringInJSONData = [serializer serializeString:@"YOUR STRING" error:&error];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:stringInJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Good luck!