# send JSON Data with URL and receive response in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios4

i m new in iphone developing, I saw some videos and example for JSON parsing, that has used JSON framework but in some examples it has used the default method "JSON Serialization" then whats the real difference between them ? ok and i can easily read Json  data from web services but How can i attach Query for data update,delete,or insert ??i don't really know how to send some data with url for services?? if there is any example link or any tutorial or any guide line then tell plz me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for your first Question :**
      The earlier IOS SDK releases doesn't contain any classes for JSON Parsing, so the only possibility was stick with third party libraries and frameworks (like SBJSon), but the past release 0f 
IOS-5 SDK ( IOS-5.1 is ready) has the class `NSJSonSerialization` which helps you to serialize and de-serialize your JSON  Object in very easy manner, also the [performance wise](http://blog.skulptstudio.com/nsjsonserialization-vs-sbjson-performance) the Apple's class took the first place. 
**Answer for your second Question :**
       The `NSJSONSerialization` class is the suitable answer for your second question. It has two methods `+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error` for parsing JSON Data and `+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error` for Creating JSON Object As well. 
       As always newbie it's pretty hard to get success in the first try. So follow this [tutorial](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/nathan-jones/getting-started-json-ios5) and [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) to know more about it, and apple always stands top at their documentation don't forgot to check [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Hope you get clear idea about it.

Comment: and ya Is there any problem when i use NSJSonSerialization instead of JSON fremwork ??

Comment: Ofcourse not. The more people have used the SBJSON Framework and rated thats the nice one too.[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844571/convert-an-object-into-json-using-sbjson-or-other-json-library) you know more about it,