# convert an object to JSON in objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, ios8.1, theos

I work in tool theos projects and i want convert an object into JSON.

I need a easy to use library with examples for converting NSObjects to JSON and back again
I check a lot of question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844571/convert-an-object-into-json-using-sbjson-or-other-json-library) but i can't use them.
I use JSONModel library but i have a lot of errors.

Anybody body have a good tutorial or a sample code to convert NSObject to JSON?

I don't have any idea whether I can created a json or not.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at my library - https://github.com/DimasSup/BaseMangedObjectModel
With it you can serialize/deserialize any your class. aslo can save it to SQLite database if needed. Also there are NetworkHelper class which help you send/receive your classes from remote server.

Comment: how can i use in tool theos project?

Comment: I do now work with theos project, but if you need serialize your own classes to JSON all what you need is copy:
BaseManagedObjectModel.h
BaseManagedObjectModel.m
Mapping.h
Mapping.m
MappingDescriptor.h
MappingDescriptor.m
TypeSelector.h
TypeSelector.m

If you dont use SQLite -  remove FMDB references. Make you classes derived from BaseManagedObjectModel, and create static method +mapping with properties which you need to serialize.